# Spring Boot REST Design for Search API

Tags: spring-boot, api-design, spring-rest

I am designing a `SpringBoot` `RESTful API` for a `Product` searching with various attributes (search can be one or more). Few of the criteria are greater than a certain amount and few are less than. In the `@RequestParam` we can take String or similar values but not any criteria.

My question is what's the best way to get the user data for these criteria in a `GET` search API call

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<OrderView>> searchOrders(...)
{
...
// call to service implementation
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm... https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/ has a good description about REST services with spring. It has also description about the different levels when it comes to RESTful principles (and you can do HATEOAS very simple and clever with spring-boot by HAL).

When you are doing a search you do not have the resource (level1) url but you want to obtain it... So it's okay (imho) to do a simple query parameter call. For example when looking at amazon.com and typing some search parameters there, you will see that they are using a simple approach:

```
https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?....&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=criteria1+criteria2+criteria3
```

They just add the keywords as a concatenated string.

There is also a interesting blog entry from apigee available:
https://apigee.com/about/blog/technology/restful-api-design-tips-search

Comment: Thank you. This is a good suggestion and I checked the Apigee document. My question is over the period of time if we need more request params then the spring controller method will have lots of method param as ```@RequestParam```. So what's the best way - a. taking as ```@RequestParam String val``` or b. as an custom object where all search fields be encapsulated and passed in controller method.

Comment: A custom databinder - as described at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder - would be a good way to do it (imho).

As an example:

`$server/api/search/area1=123,456,789$area2=123,444,55$area3=bla`

So you could do an custom data binding which is able to parse a string like `area1=123,456,789$area2=123,444,55$area3=bla`
and create a custom object... This would be very generic and provide ability for changes in future

Comment: That's correct. Custom data binder gave much flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

In this article **[Spring Boot: How to design efficient REST API?](https://medium.com/quick-code/spring-boot-how-to-design-efficient-search-rest-api-c3a678b693a0)**, I explained how to develop a REST  API for search. As an example, you found the code and screenshots of postman in this article.

As optimization with one endpoint, I can get several results: resources are sorted, filtered, and paginated.

You do not deal with a lot of code (check of query param and all the control in your controller): the library  **specification-arg-resolver** makes that with no problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of existing instruments is you need search/filtering.
I use [springfilter](https://github.com/turkraft/springfilter) for this. It's *extremely easy* to config, quite powerful and one more benefit is that there is existing JS library for client.

Another good library for search seems to be [rsql-builder](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser).